# Use AutoLayout to design simple app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have this simple app.
[image: my app]

How can I use AutoLayout to make the app look like this on all devices? I played around with pinning, but I do not understand how it works. I have read online how to use AutoLayout but I am still confused.

If someone could tell me how to add constraints between the two labels at the bottom, and get those stuck in place, I could probably go from there.

Comment: You should concrete question and not ask people to do something for you. Try edit your question to generalize it for many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Pin Now Playing to the top, both sides, but leave the bottom un marked

Pin image view top under the now playing label, also pin to horizontal center (you might want to pin aspect ratio as well)

Pin the next 2 labels the same as Now Playing (but only after pinning the first two items)

Create a UIView container, add both bottom images to it, center the container and pin it either bottom or top. Pin the contained images with 0 on all sides or whatever offset you want between them.

Comment: I can pin everything properly except for the buttons in the container. I pinned the container to the bottom, and both sides. How can I centre the two buttons in the container with a bit of offset between them?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this will work but it is worth a try.
When you have your below 2 blocks. Add 1 block on the left ( extra ) and another extra one on the right. 
Hide them, and now apply your layout / autolayout -> add auto constraints.

Hope this helps.

In case it doesnt help, check where it fails, and try to create invisible thingy's like those blocks i just mentioned and pin to them. This helps your app with laying it down.

Good luck.

Comment: How do I add auto constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **Any/Any** at the bottom of Xcode and there you can edit your program so it looks the same with every IOS device. Also pay attention to the little details at the bottom of the Base Value each base value is a different IOS Device.